# How to uninstall Mercury Mail Server 32 for Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

I wanted to know how to uninstall Mercury from my computer. I've tried to look for the uninstall option but none found.

Answer (score 3):

Notes from [Mercury:Installation](http://wiki.pmail.com/index.php?title=Mercury:Installation) wiki on [Uninstalling Mercury Service](http://wiki.pmail.com/index.php?title=Mercury:Installation#Uninstalling_Mercury_Service)

> The Mercury installer is a file copy process. Mercury does also not register itself as an installed software under Windows. Therefore there exists no uninstaller for Mercury.
>
> You use the standard Windows commandline SC to uninstall each Mercury Windows Service instance that you have installed. The example below assumes you named the service Mercury32.

```
C:\> SC DELETE MERCURY32
```

> In order to uninstall Mercury/32 from your machine, simply delete the shortcuts from the windows start-menu and also delete the entire Mercury Directory.